# What is the name of child process after posix fork() & win32 CreateProcess()?

Tags: c, winapi, posix

I learnt that child process gets new process id after running api,

posix standard fork()

&
 i
win32 CreateProcess()

Does the child process gets unique process name different from parent process in both unix and windows world? Because i need to measure the min/max of cpu&mem utilization of all the processes(using names) running on a device.

Comment: where is the question, and they get unique porcess IDs not Names

Comment: question is in the title, does that look fine?

Comment: Can i do something during fork() or CreateProcess() to get the different names for child process?

Comment: At least on Windows you need to define what you mean by process name

Comment: David, On Linux, it is the executable name with -o option that you give while compile and linking your source code. On windows, i think the executable name is given in solution file properties of VStudio

Comment: @user You have to be precise. What's the name for an executable not written in VS. Also, if you want the name as entered in VS, then right off the bat you know that it will be the same for all processes based on that exe. You do need to define what you mean by name.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think your question is correct. I wrongly assumed that PCB on linux and windows has process id & process names. sorry about that. So, David, If i don't mention executable name in project properties of VStudio, What is the name assigned to the process? Does windows OS give some name? In linux, i guess, if you dont mention executable name, it shows as a.out as process name.

Comment: This is the point. Processes on Windows are not identified by name so your question is moot. Why do you care about the name? The system does not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49129/discussion-between-user3317808-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process does not have a name in Windows.  It has a unique process ID, and a filename which the process was launched from.  Everything in the Win32 API that deals with processes is based on process IDs only, not on names.  There are various API functions that allow you to retrieve the filename that was used to create any given process ID, so if you need to locate a process by filename, you have to enumerate the running process IDs hunting for the filename manually.

Answer (score 1):

No, parent and child will get same name. in linux it will be same name. only the pid will be different. you can read this [link](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/processname.html) if you want to change name of child in linux

Comment: But this actually does not change the process name which is part of PCB, correct?

Comment: @user3317808 ya it doesn't. and mostly you cant change it. this link i provided changes commandline name. so it will not affect PCB.